# Problem with CLRProfiler

Tags: .net, clrprofiler

I am trying to use Microsoft's [CLRProfiler](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=A362781C-3870-43BE-8926-862B40AA0CD0&displaylang=en) to profile my fairly large app, and it is crashing whenever it tries to write (or read) a log file. Ironically, the exact bug is documented on the [MS 'Feedback' site](http://209.85.129.132/search?q=cache:I6-DV7i__YUJ:connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx%3FFeedbackID%3D255678+CLRProfiler.ReadNewLog.ReadFile() as being not reproducible, and seems never to have been fixed. I am getting a `NullReferenceException` at:

```
CLRProfiler.ReadNewLog.ReadFile(Int64 startFileOffset, Int64 endFileOffset, ReadLogResult readLogResult)
at CLRProfiler.MainForm.checkProcessTimer_Tick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.OnTick(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.TimerNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Does anyone have any ideas how I could go about either getting help or, ideally getting the damn thing to run properly? Plaintive calls for help on MSDN have been ignored... Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CLR Profiler is quite unstable, I also experienced many crashes with it.

One hint that I have heard at PDC is to use it only as a snapshot tool: don't collect the mem usage information during the run of the application, but stop the app at a point where you know you have the mem problem already, and make a mem snapshot.

This way it is much more stable, and usually from the reference graph you anyway can find out what causes the leak.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that is a dead avenue. Perhaps try jetBrains [dotTRACE](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/index.html); you can get a free [10 day trial](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/download/index.html) to see if it is suitable.

Answer (score 0):

We faced a similar problem while debugging a crashing mammoth on a remote Citrix Server which CLRProfiler failed to analyze.

We were able to find the problem using [WinDbg](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/debugstart.mspx#a)

Additionally this can also help [CorDbg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6zb7c8d(VS.80).aspx)